# Is it correct to say I got attacked?

Tags: american-english, passive-voice

I heard native speakers rarely use passive expressions.

Is it correct to say something like "I got attacked"?

e.g.

> - I’m attacked by him.
> - I got attacked by him.

Comment: It's not true. There seems to be an unsubstantiated guidance against passive constructions in general. Many more people use passive constructions (certainly informally) than the prohibitive style guidance that seems so common. There are also good reason to use passive construction in some context. Your example is one of them. But I would keep it as just *I got attacked*. *I'm attacked* doesn't sound normal.

Comment: Why not say, "I was attacked" or "He attacked me"? Sounds much more natural to me than "I got attacked by him".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I got attacked" is an acceptable idiomatic way of saying "I *was* attacked", referring to a *past* event.

"I'm attacked" is a contraction of "I am attacked", and is in the present tense. The correct way to say that you are presently under attack is "I am *being* attacked".

Comment: Thanks so much! Very helpful! :D